# populate checkbox in view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

Passed a populated 'Orders' list to the supplier view page. Run through each order with a foreach and display on screen. All working fine, expect where it says if the order has been shipped or not ATM it has the text 'True' or 'False' I want to change this to a clickable checkbox.

```
<td width="15%">@_order.Shipped</td>  //This shows true or false.
```

Tried:

```
<td width="15%"><input type="checkbox" name="@_order.Shipped" value="@_order.Shipped"></td>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td width="15%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shipped" value="@(_order.Shipped ? "1" : "0")" @(_order.Shipped ? "checked" : "")>
</td>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, try with `@(order.Shipped ...` I'm not sure about the correct name of your variable

Comment: thanks for the reply ended up using <td width="15%">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => _order.Shipped)</td>